# Scan web page get header, footer, menu, sub menu and hyperlink using PHP

Tags: php, html

Is there any  way to get header, footer, menu, sub menu, banners and hyperlinks  by scanning the web page using PHP?

If anyone have an idea please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scrapping code for it,first parse the url with `$a=file_get_contents($url);` and than parse the json output `$arrjson=json_decode($a);` use `->` operator to traverse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can scan and parse whatever you need from a web page's HTML. But please be noted that you should be aware of the page's HTML structure and that structure should never change ideally because if it does your parsing logic might fail.

The steps involve:

1. read the web page. You can use either fopen() or file_get_contents() or CURL. I would suggest CURL as it provides many useful options like connecting from a proxy. For the first 2 methods, it is required that ["fopen wrappers"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) are enabled.
2. you may use regular expression to parse specific content from the returned HTML but those could be tricky to generate. I would suggest using DOMDocument library as it easily allows to read any HTML tag or attribute. Play around with it and you'll enjoy it.

By the way, may I ask why would you like to read so much from a web page? Web pages are normally read to read dynamic information but headers, footers and menus are almost static.

Comment: my requirement is  after enter the  url of the webpage, scan it, find the categorized parts and replace them

Comment: do you have any logic to find out them in web page. ? please let me know.

Comment: I don't have a ready-made logic for it. It will depend on what webpage you need to parse and the HTML structure

Comment: it is not for particular html structure, it must parse the all the web page. how many possible out of 6 categories(header, footer, menu buttons, action buttons, banners and hyperlinks). please let me know.

Comment: But you need to know before-hand what part of HTML represents the header, footer, menus and other sections. And how to recognize where a particular section (header, footer etc) starts and ends. The code just could not recognize the start and end points on its own. For example, a header can be as simple as `<div><img src='logo.jpg'></div>` or might contain any number of other HTML statements or CSS classes